# DataGridView is not updating after second row

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview

i am trying a few things in WinForms for the first time. I have a problem which appears very trivial to me but then i am not a WinForms guy.. searched a lot but could not find the solution.

Below is the code, don't worry about the content itself, its just test code. The problem is that when i click the AddNew button a row gets added to gridview but after that no row gets added, no matter how many times user clicks on the AddNew button. You can see that in the Image below.

Can you point out why no rows are getting added to the gridview after a row has been added.
AddNew button just works for one click. While as it should add the second row again and again.

Thanks in advance.

```
    public partial class JobCard : UserControl
    {
        List<Work> works = new List<Work>();
        BindingSource bs = new BindingSource();

        public JobCard()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            works.Add(new Work() { S_No = 1, JobCategoryId = 1, JobCategoryName = "electricals", JobId = 1, JobName = "lights", Labour = 1, MaterialName = "tape", PartName = "headlight" });

            bs.DataSource = works;
            dataGridView1.AutoGenerateColumns = true;
            dataGridView1.DataSource = bs;
         }

        private void btnAddNew_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            works.Add(new Work() { S_No = 2, JobCategoryId = 2, JobCategoryName = "electricals", JobId = 2, JobName = "lights", Labour = 2, MaterialName = "tape", PartName = "headlight" });
            dataGridView1.DataSource = works;
        }

     }
```

[image: Application snapshot]

Comment: i think the problem lies in your button code: dataGridView1.DataSource = works. You should be resetting the bindingsource.

Comment: try: bs.DataSource = null; bs.DataSource = works;

Comment: :* thanks it works.. :) post it as answer so that i can accept it.

Comment: actually i was already doing bs.Datasource= works, but bs.Datasource= null did it along with it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to reset the datasource of your bindingsource.

Try

```
private void btnAddNew_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   ...
   bs.DataSource = null;
   bs.DataSource = works;
}
```